# Updating an HSQLDB table from Eclipse

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, hsqldb

I'm currently using Java to access a .sql file (called patient.sql). Running queries and updating the table works well while the program is running, but the changes aren't made on disk.

So, for example, I have a 30 node database with some fields including caseID (primary key) and Hospital. I want to change the Hospital of the node with caseID = Case29. To do this, I use the following code:

```
        // Prepare a statement to update a record
        String sql = "UPDATE patient SET Hospital='CX' WHERE caseID = 'Case29'";

        // Execute the insert statement
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

I have checked this and seen that it works (using a quick System.out.println()). However, when I finish the program and open the patient.sql, my change has not been registered. How can I save this change made?

Cheers

EDIT: I'm using HSQLDB

Comment: You need to commit your transaction as it looks like. This might help : http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-transaction-example/

Comment: How are you checking the result with println - what is the sql query you are doing there. Also what RDBMS are you using as these have different transaction management

Comment: You should at least tell us the name of the DBMS you are using. HSQLDB, or whatever?

Comment: What is the connection url you use to connect to the database?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using HSQLDB changes are stored in a .log file until SHUTDOWN is called.
After a SHUTDOWN, all changes are moved to a .script file.

One description of HSQLDB files here:

http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch01.html

In your case I suspect no SHUTDOWN has been called.